# update document if field not exist

Tags: mongodb

I have two collection in mongodb: `ColA`, `ColB`.

In `colA`:

```
    "_id" : "89479574905"
    "NETWORK" : "AAA",
    "BUSINESS_ID" : "148013"
```

In `colB`:

```
 "_id" : "78787878"
"NETWORK" : "BBB",
"BUSINESS_ID" : "148456",
"BUSINESS_NAME" : "Hello",
"BUSINESS_URL" : "www.some.net",
"LOCATION" : "Delhi"
```

I want to update `colA` so that the result should be:

```
"_id" : "89479574905"
"NETWORK" : "AAA",
"BUSINESS_ID" : "148013",
"BUSINESS_NAME" : "Hello",
"BUSINESS_URL" : "www.some.net",
"LOCATION" : "Delhi"
```

If the same field occurs in `colA`, then do not update only insert the other fields.

How would you do that ?

Comment: I you don't have many documents in your collection, I would use your document from colB and use it as base document. Next loop over your keys of your document from colA and update all the values of your base document. Finally update the document in de database. I know it's not an ideal situation but it's the only thing I can think of at the moment.

Comment: I think you are missing some explanation, some ID's. How can you identify which document from ColA should be updated with which document from ColB? From your example you cannot identify that.

Comment: see the updated question

Comment: Thomas I have many documents in my collection. count is about 2million